# numpy.savetxt() rounding values

Tags: python, save

I'm using numpy.savetxt() to save an array, but its rounding my values to the first decimal point, which is a problem. anyone have any clue how to change this?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the precision through changing fmt parameter. For example np.savetxt('tmp.txt',a, fmt='%1.3f') would leave you with an output with the precision of first three decimal points